# Can I use DNS-over-TLS below Android Pie?

Tags: security, internet, privacy, data-connection, dns

Unfortunately DoT isn't part of Android below version 9. Is there a workaround [app](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dns%20tls%20apk&ia=web) or should I better install [LineageOS 16](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/lineageos-16-supported-devices-list-and-downloads-android-pie-9-0/) on my old smartphone device?

Comment: You can set up `dnscrypt-proxy`.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone&hl=en_US